# Interface stating that class has to have an ICollection<T> Property

Tags: c#, interface

I like to create an interface stating the a class must have at least one property of ICollection

```
   public interface ILinked<T> where T : class, IModel
    {
        ICollection<T> LinkedT { get; set; }
    }
```

but I want the implementing class to be free to choose the actual name of the property. Is this possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to enforce this specific criteria? Which problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: How does code consuming one of these objects make use of this interface?

Comment: I'm writing an MVC application. For the model I use EF. Many Model classes have navigation properties. Most models have an edit/create ViewModel. The models implement an IModel interface (just stating they have an Int Id property) and (depending on the other models thery are linked to) one or more ICollection<T> LinkedT properties. When getting back the info of a post action I fill up the model with the data from the ViewModel. For the 'linked' properties this results in a List<int>. The list of the Id's of the linked stuff.

Comment: To make life easier I have a set of extension methods for the ILinked<T> interfaces that compare the Model and ViewModel and 'synch' the data. Those exntension methods have the same structure and logic. The only difference is that they operate on different classes T and different LinkedT properties. I like to make it more generic and have only one extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible; in C#, an interface cannot define the type and access modifiers alone without stating a name.

As you formulate the requirement to have 'at least one property if ICollection', perhaps the problem can be solved by defining a property of type `ICollection<ICollection<object>>`.

Answer (score 2):

*In a way*, yes. You just have to specify *which* property of your class is the one implementing the interface property -- after all, there could be multiple properties with that signature and the compiler needs to know what to do when `someVariableOfTypeILinkedT.LinkedT` is accessed. That can be done by [implementing the interface *explicitly*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

For that, C# requires a bit of boiler-plate code...

```
class MyClass : ILinked<MyParameter> {
    public ICollection<MyParameter> SomeArbitraryProperty { get; set; }

    ICollection<MyParameter> ILinked<MyParameter>.LinkedT
    { 
        get { return SomeArbitraryProperty; }
        set { SomeArbitraryProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

...whereas VB.NET is more concise in this case and allows you to map the implementation to the interface method directly:

```vb
Class MyClass
    Implements ILinked(Of MyParameter)

    Public Property SomeArbitraryProperty As ICollection(Of MyParameter) _
        Implements ILinked(Of MyParameter).LinkedT
End Class
```